# Show that if $K\triangleleft A\times B$ is non-abelian, then at least one of $K\cap A,K\cap B$ is non-trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Let $A,B$ be groups, $K\triangleleft A\times B$ be a non-abelian normal subgroup. Show that at least one of the intersection $K\cap A$, $K\cap B$ is non-trivial.

My attempts:

We assume by contradiction that $K\cap A$, $K\cap B$ are both trivial. We can show that the natural homomorphism:
$$ \phi: A\times B \rightarrow (A/K\cap A)\times (B/K\cap B) $$
has kernel $\ker\phi=K$, therefore by assumption $A\times B$ is isomorphic to $(A\times B)/K$, I believe this implies that $K$ is Abelian, otherwise there will be some non-trivial commutator lies in K, therefore trivial in $(A\times B)/K$.

I feel a bit unsafe about this proof, I am not sure that '$A\times B$ is isomorphic to $(A\times B)/K$' can happen. Are there any corrections or comments? THANKS!

Edit: This proof seems problematic, maybe $\ker\phi\neq K$ ? Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Assume $K$ is normal with $K\cap A=1$. Show first that $(a,b),(a',b)\in K$ implies $a=a'$. Now conjugate by $(x,1)$ to deduce that $(a,b)\in K$ implies $a\in Z(A)$.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Thanks for your nice proof!:) (I kept trying to construct a homomorphism with kernel $K$ or $K\cap A$...

Comment: Wait, $K$ has two components $\forall k\in K, k=(a, b)$, but $A$ has only one component, when you write $K\cap A$, do you mean $K\cap A\times e$?

Comment: @MathFail Yes, by default I identify $A$ with $A\times \{e\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K$ is nonabelian, it contains two elements, $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$, that do not commute. Thus, either $a$ does not commute with $a'$, or $b$ does not commute with $b'$ (or both). Say, without loss of generality, that $a$ does not commute with $a'$.

If $b$ is trivial, we are done (since $a$ cannot be trivial). Otherwise, conjugating by $(a',1)$ we get $(a'a(a')^{-1},b)\in K$. Multiplying by $(a,b)^{-1}$ we obtain an element of $K\cap (A\times{1})$ which is nontrivial.

The assumption that $K$ is nonabelian is key. Without it, even if $K$ is nontrivial, you could have for example a subgroup of the form $(x,f(x))$ where $x$ ranges over a nontrivial subgroup $H\leq Z(A)$, and $f\colon H\to Z(B)$ is a one-to-one homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! I got it:)